# Why do the asymptotes appear in the graph of $u$ against $v$ for the thin lens equation and what does this represent?

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics, lenses

For the thin lens equation,
$$\frac{1}{v} = \frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{f}$$ when $u$ and $v$ are plotted to determine $f$ you get a graph like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyTN2.jpg). Why do the asymptotes appear and why can we use them as a way to find $f$? Can the $1/f$ part of the equation be thought of as translating the graph? Furthermore, what would this then actually represent in physical terms?

Comment: Use built-in function to add images. Not an external link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do the asymptotes appear and why can we use them as a way to find $f$?

First Why asymptotes appear?

$$\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{f}$$

That's the same thing i.e. the lens formula.
$$\Rightarrow y=\frac{xf}{x+f}, $$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -f}y=+\infty$$
or $$\lim_{u\rightarrow -f}v=+\infty$$

What does means is basically if you set the location of the object at focal length, you get the image at infinity.

Now Why we use this? First, it's not the only way to determine focal length but It's showing you the way to find focal length by just watching the image and vary the object locations.

> Can the $1/f$ part of the equation be thought of as translating the graph?

No! Just plot the graph, It's not translating rather It's changing the asymptotes.

> Furthermore, what would this then actually represent in physical terms?

It's the inverse of focal length that's all. You can call it the Power of lense.

Comment: Double-check your conventions. The limit as you've written it is $\lim_{u\rightarrow f}v=f/2$, which is not particularly interesting. You want $\lim_{v\rightarrow f}u$ or $\lim_{u\to - f}v$ instead. Ditto with x and y.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't recognize that. Why the down vote?

Comment: A marked "edit" at the end is hardly helpful. It's significantly better to actually fix the post.

Comment: I did that too.

Comment: Then the addendum is harmful as written. If you have something specific to say about OP's handling of conventions, then say it outright. Otherwise there's no need to comment.

Comment: Obeyed. Pardon me

Comment: I'm not giving any orders. I'm pointing out problems I see, and that's it. You can use those suggestions or not at your discretion, always.

Comment: Though, as friendly feedback, if you feel this comment interaction was rough, perhaps you should re-examine how you're comment to OP would look like to a new user ;-). (which is to say, a smoother tone, and leading by example by doing the edit yourself, are often much more effective at helping new users learn the ropes.)

Comment: No, It's all right. It wasn't rough. I'm not that used to English that much I guess. So I should be careful using these words. Sorry If you find it harsh.